# ASM to parse .class against the rule defined in xml

Tags: java, parsing, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM bytecode reader to parse .class file present in the code.
But I want to get the particular string defined in the class which inturn will be mentioned inside the xml.

So how to use XML and parse the string present in .class. As I see there is ClassReader only takes .class as a parameter not the XML or any other format.

I am using something like this:

```
InputStream in=String.class.getResourceAsStream("/java/lang/String.class");

ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(in);

classReader.accept(v, 0);
```

please tell me is there any way to parse .class against the rule defined in xml file?

Thanks in advance...

Yashu

Comment: The visitor you accept on he reader (v in your sample) is supposed to contain all the custom logic. Pass in a subclass of ClassVisitor that does what you want (including the XML-related stuff).

Comment: Why do you expect `ClassReader` to take your XML as input? How should it know what to do with it? There’s a point in the programmer’s life where he has to implement the desired behavior by himself.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, I was trying in the same way but didn't get success, as I am very new to java to didn't think about it :) thanks alot

Comment: If you are "very new to Java", perhaps you should start with a task less complex than parsing Java bytecode!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to do the following: You are receiving a *.class* file and you then want to extract some sort of information from it which is specified in an XML file. If this is so: ASM does not need to know about what kind of information you are requiring. ASM will plainly read the class file. If you plainly want to know if some specific `String` is part of the class's constant pool, you could use a short cut for being notified of that: Override the `ClassReader`'s `readUTF8(int, char[])` method like this:

```
public MyClassReader extends ClassReader {

  private final Set<String> constantPoolStrings = new HashSet<String>();

  // Add constructors here

  @Override 
  public String readUTF8(int index, char[] buf) {
    String value = super.readUTF8(index, buf);
    constantPoolStrings.add(value);
    return value;
  }

  public boolean hasString(String value) {
    // From the details in your comment, we will need to do a fuzzy search.
    for(String poolString : constantPoolStrings) {
      if(poolString.contains(value)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Of course you have to provide some logic that knows what `String` you are interested in: If you for example have an XML file that contains specific words you will need to parse this file and extract these words. You can than query the `MyClassReader` for these `String`s.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I tried the same and accessed String in this way                                                            InputStream in=ASMHelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("Test.class");
        MyClassReader classReader=new MyClassReader(in);
        classReader.hasString("lang");                               but its always gives false as a result even though string lang is present in test.class . please help....

Comment: Can you post `Test.class`?

Comment: Hi , My Test.java is just printing a String containing "lang"                 public class Test {

 
 public static void main(String argv[]) {
 
  String print = "Hello lang";
  
  System.out.println(print);
 
}}
pls help me why I am not able to get the string and result as true?

Comment: and as you said in your answer "Of course you have to provide some logic that knows what String you are interested in." I am not doing anything in MyClassReader class. What logic to provide?? public boolean hasString(String value) is completely independent of readUTF8 , how it will search. please please reply.. it will be so kind and helpful to u.

Comment: That explains your mismatch: You are looking for `lang` but your string pool only contains a string `Hello lang`. The class in my answer works as follows: It populates a set with all your `String`s when the class is read. This set will then be used to check if it contains your **exact** `String`. See my updated answer for help on how to solve your problem.

Comment: its still giving false :( MyClassReader class is the same as you posted in your answer, main method inside the same class contains, public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    
    InputStream in=MyClassReader.class.getResourceAsStream("Test.class");
         MyClassReader classReader=new MyClassReader(in);
         
         System.out.println("found string :" + classReader.hasString("Hello lang")); 
   }

Comment: output comes as:   found string :false ,    why it is coming so if i am giving exact string present in test.class as "Hello lang"  pls help & Thanks for your replies :)